# Install Corel AfterShot Pro 3

Tags: software-installation

AfterShot says they support Ubuntu 16.04, but the below installation results in an icon that doesn't launch.

It says libgstreamer is not installed, but according to Synaptic, it is.

```
????  :~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i AfterShotPro3.deb
[sudo] password for ???:          
Selecting previously unselected package aftershot3x64.
(Reading database ... 191523 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack AfterShotPro3.deb ...
Unpacking aftershot3x64 (340297:3.4.0.297) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aftershot3x64:
 aftershot3x64 depends on libgstreamer0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer0.10-0 is not installed.
 aftershot3x64 depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 is not installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install missing dependencies.

```
 sudo apt install -f
```